# Partial derivative with Matlab Symbolic Toolbox for Lagrangian equations of motion

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, derivative

I'm trying to derive [Lagrangian equations of motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics) in Matlab using the symbolic toolbox. This involves partial derivatives of a function and your coordinates, but matlab seems to not accept this.

So I would do this in Matlab:

```
syms t x(t)             % t: time, x(t) position dependent on time
m = sym('m');           % mass, a constant parameter
T = m/2*diff(x,t)^2;    % kinetic energy
dTdx = diff(T,x);
ddTdxDotdt = diff( diff(T,diff(x,t)), t);
```

But as soon as I try to differentiate anything in x (or diff(x,t)), Matlab complains:

```
Error using mupadmex
Error in MuPAD command: The variable is invalid. [stdlib::diff]

Error in sym/diff (line 44)
R = mupadmex('symobj::diff', S.s, x.s, int2str(n));
```

Does anyone know the proper way of handling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab ought to be able to do this as you have it written, but I think that it doesn't like taking derivatives with respect to a [`symfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symfun.html). Type `whos` in the command window and you'll see that `x` is listed as a `symfun` while `t` is just a `sym`. The help for [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/diff.html) kind of indicates this limitation. It won't event try to take the derivative of a constant with respect to `x(t)`: `diff(1,x)` "complains" just the same. Unless newer versions of Matlab fix this (I'm on R2012b) I think you only option may be to come up with a scheme using two instances of `x`.

Comment: So, using the 'subs' function to change between the symfun and sym versions of x, D(x) etc.?

Comment: Yes, I think it may be possible via `subs`, though convoluted. See [this thread on Matlab Central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/312204), for example. You might also look into what [this File Exchange submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23037-lagranges-equations/content/Lagrange.m) is doing.